# Calling an function without reference to object

Tags: c#

Noob here in C#, so I'm having an issue trying to call a function in C# with system event args. I know the issue isn't with system event args, but what is the correct way I should call this type of function?

> Error1: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'ConsoleApplication3.Program.Reject_call(object,
>   System.EventArgs)'
>
> Error2: An object reference is required for the non-static field,
>   method, or property 'ConsoleApplication3.Program.Accept_call(object,
>   System.EventArgs)'

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.AudioVideo;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
    //holds the Lync client instance
    private static LyncClient _client;
    //holds the reference to the conversation associated with this window
    private Conversation conversation;
    //self participant's AvModality
    private AVModality avModality;

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Obtains the lync client instance
        _client = LyncClient.GetClient();
        consoleInputReadRoutine();
        _client.ConversationManager.ConversationAdded += ConversationManager_ConversationAdded;
        _client.ConversationManager.ConversationRemoved += ConversationManager_ConversationRemoved;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void ConversationManager_ConversationAdded(object sender, ConversationManagerEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.AudioVideo].ModalityStateChanged += Program_ModalityStateChanged;
    }

    static void Program_ModalityStateChanged(object sender, ModalityStateChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Modality state changed " + String.Format("{0} => {1}", e.OldState, e.NewState));
    }

    static void consoleInputReadRoutine()
    {

        bool done = false;
        while(!done){

            string input = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from user
            Console.WriteLine("user input {0}\n", input);

            // Set exit condition.
            if(String.Compare(input, "exit") == 0){
                done = true;
            }
            else if (String.Compare(input, "reject") == 0)
            {
                //Do a reject call.
                Reject_call(null, new EventArgs());
            }
            else if(String.Compare(input, "answer") == 0)
            {
                //Do a answer call.
                Accept_call(null, new EventArgs());
            }
        }
    }

    // Accepts an incoming call: AvModality.Accept()
    private void Accept_call(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //accepts an incoming invite (syncronous operation)
        avModality.Accept();
    }

    // Rejects an incoming call: AvModality.Reject()
    private void Reject_call(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //rejects an incoming invite (which will disconnect the call)
        //the ModalityDisconnectReason may be used to specify a reason to the caller side
        //the reason may be shown on the Lync client conversation window
        avModality.Reject(ModalityDisconnectReason.Decline);
    }

    static void ConversationManager_ConversationRemoved(object sender, ConversationManagerEventArgs e)
    {
        //Exit out of program if you wish after conversation is removed.
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want to call/access a function/field/property without an instance of the class, then the function must be static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling a instance method (`private void Accept_call`) from a `static` one (`static void consoleInputReadRoutine`).

Given that this is a console app, you likely just want to make `Accept_call` static. In general, if this were a *normal* object, you would want to make everything non-static.

```
private static void Accept_call(object sender, EventArgs e)

private static void Reject_call(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Class members used by these functions would also need to be static. `avModality` in particular.

Comment: And make AVModality avModality static

Answer (score 1):

You need to either create an instance of your `Program` class via the `new` operator or mark `Reject_call` and `Accept_call` as `static`.